# How do I achieve this OUT and IN tracking in barcode application?

Tags: automation, barcode, inventory-management

I am planning to develop a inventory management system for containers tracking using barcodes.
I am facing one problem, I don't know how I can find better solution for it.

I will explain the project briefly,

In our company, we use containers to supply materials to the customers and after few days the empty containers are returned back to the company.

(In simple, OUT and IN tracking)

I need to create a automation software for tracking the containers.

Containers are of different sizes.
Lets consider a vehicle like TATA ACE.
Metal containers are big in size. So only 2 metal containers can fit in TATA ACE. I can able to stick barcode label to each metal containers and scan it when it is going out and when it is returned I scan the barcode for IN entry. Here I am planning to use handheld barcode reader(PDA). It will take only few seconds since containers are less in numbers.

Plastic containers are small in size. More than 60 Plastic containers can fit in TATA ACE.
This is what is my problem, I feel it would be difficult to stick 50 barcode labels for each plastic containers when it is going out and when it is returned it would be difficult to scan each containers for IN entry. It will take lot of time.

Can you suggest some idea for tracking the plastic containers effectively?

Is there any alternative solution to achieve this?

Should I make it manual? If so, then the automation fails.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the RFID method to track it? Basically you will have RFID tag on each plastic container which will be read by proximity as soon as the truck arrives at your facility

Comment: Ya. I thought of considering RFID technology, the problem is RFID tags will not be safe since the materials are handled by many people at different environments. The same problem happens with barcode sticker.